# Anomaly with linking objects in Java binary tree implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I have implemented a simple binary tree program, but there is a problem I encounter while traversing the tree, only root element is accessed. I suspect the nodes aren't linked. I tried my best to figure out the problem but didn't find anything wrong with my code.

I tried printing the data from the insertion function, right before exiting the function, which did print the data correctly.

```
public class BinaryTree {

    Node root;

    public void addNode(int data){

        Node newNode = new Node(data);

        if(root == null){
            root = newNode;
        }
        else{
            Node currentNode = root;
            while(true){
                if(data <= currentNode.data){
                    currentNode = currentNode.leftChild;
                    if(currentNode == null){
                        currentNode = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                } 
                else{
                    currentNode = currentNode.rightChild;
                    if(currentNode == null){
                        currentNode = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void inorderTraversal(Node currentNode){

        if(currentNode != null){

            inorderTraversal(currentNode.leftChild);

            System.out.print(currentNode.data + " ");

            inorderTraversal(currentNode.rightChild);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Indeed, you never add the new node to the tree. All you're doing is assign the new node to a local variable. You need to have something like `leafNode.leftChild = newNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you are not adding the new node correctly to the tree during the recursive step.  The logic you should be using is when you a reach a node whose left or right pointer be `null`, *and* the new node belongs in that direction, you should add the new node either to the left or right.  Otherwise, keep traversing until you reach such node.

```
while(true) {
    if (data <= currentNode.data) {
        if (currentNode.leftChild == null) {
            currentNode.leftChild = newNode;
            return;
        }
        else {
            currentNode = currentNode.leftChild;
        }
    else {
        if (currentNode.rightChild == null) {
            currentNode.rightChild = newNode;
            return;
        }
        else {
            currentNode = currentNode.rightChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the above simple algorithm for adding new nodes is not guaranteed to necessarily result in a balanced binary tree.  To ensure that, you would have to add more logic which handle rebalancing.

Comment: Ok,  I got it.  Thank you very much. And yes I know this code won't create a balanced tree,  I planned to learn and implement blancing after this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the element to the `left` or `right` child. You are just assigning it to the local variable `currentNode` - which is not linked to the tree.

Follow the below code to put inside the `while` loop & it should work for you.

```
            if(data <= currentNode.data){
                if(currentNode.leftChild == null){
                    currentNode.leftChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
                else {
                     currentNode = currentNode.leftChild;
                }
            } 
            else{
                if(currentNode.rightChild == null){
                    currentNode.rightChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
                else {
                     currentNode = currentNode.rightChild;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Now this is just a copy of my answer.